# Form validation, throwing exception which class should be responsible good practices

Tags: java

Is there maybe a rule of thumb for which class should be responsible for form validation?

A short example:

I have 2 classes PreferencesUI.java and NormalDistributionPreferences.java

NormalDistributionPreferences.java has all methods static and allows from different parts of my app to set and get values from Preferences API/register.

example:

```
public static void setAccuracyAuto(boolean auto){
    preferences.putBoolean("AccuracyAuto", auto);
}
```

and in PreferencesUI.java after user fills out the form and presses save this is executed:

```
private void saveButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    if(trapeziumRuleRadioButton.isSelected()){
        NormalDistributionPreferences.setIntegrationType("TrapeziumRule");

    }else if(midPointRuleRadioButton.isSelected()){
        NormalDistributionPreferences.setIntegrationType("MidPointRule");

    }else{
       NormalDistributionPreferences.setIntegrationType("SimpsonsRule");
    }
    NormalDistributionPreferences.setAccuracyAuto(accuracyCheckBox.isSelected());
    NormalDistributionPreferences.setAccuracy(0);
    dispose();
}
```

My question is should setters in preferences class throw exception if user chooses something that I do not want them to choose and then in saveButtonActionPerformed have try and catch - catch that would display an error? Accuracy integer should always be positive and for some integration types only even should that rule be enforced in preferencesUI when saving data or in normalDistributionPreferences.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure on what the question is, but if it's regarding validation of input, the sooner that's done the better. Do content validation ASAP and give some form of feedback

Answer (score 0):

In my mind every entity must preserve it's integrity, so if the preferences have limited legal value bound you must guaranty this integrity in setters methods or by AOP. If some client classes try to violate from these policies then they catch some proper exceptions and handling these exceptional situations are duty of these client classes the pass this illegal values.